# Is there a library similar to Vueuse but for React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, vueuse

Instead of having many dependencies for individual hooks, I am interested in a single curated and tested library like Vueuse, but for React. Does something like this exist?

For instance, in Vue projects I would often use https://vueuse.org/core/useStorage/, https://vueuse.org/core/computedAsync/ and https://vueuse.org/shared/useToggle/, but many others as well.

The list of built in React Hooks seems quite limited: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found https://ahooks.js.org/ which does what I need

Answer (score 2):

What about https://github.com/streamich/react-use? Otherwise you could try using @vueuse directly in your react components thank to [reactivue](https://github.com/antfu/reactivue)!